# Not all columns appear in SQL query

Tags: sql, excel, vba

In this Excel project, I want to copy an entire SQL table into Excel using this code:

```
Sub search()

Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim dataset As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sqlQry As String, sConnect As String

sqlQry = "select [Project],[Machine],[Mold],[ Desc],[Model],[Name],[Repair Type],[Entry],[Date],[Time],[Details],[Status],[Division],[A. Stroke],[P. Stroke],[PIC] from [SQLTEST].[dbo].[REPAIRLOG]"

sConnect = "[redacted]"
conn.Open sConnect

Set dataset = New ADODB.Recordset

    dataset.Open sqlQry, conn
    Sheet1.Cells(6, 1).CopyFromRecordset dataset
    dataset.Close

conn.Close
Set dataset = Nothing

End Sub
```

When executing the sub, only the 1st 10 columns out of 16 columns appears. What happened to the other 6?

**Edit:**

After posting I tried to remove the first 10 columns in the SQL query and start off from `Details` onwards. Nothing appears.

But then when I remove `Details` from the query, the remaining columns behind it can appear. So I can deduce that `Details` column in my database has issues.

But not sure what's the cause. Its the only field in SQL whose data type is `nvarchar(MAX)` while everything else is `nvarchar(50)` or `datetime`.

Comment: Can you turn on the word wrap in excel and see if columns are exist ?

Comment: Done that. Still only have those 10 columns only. No hidden columns anywhere.

Comment: If you change the field order, does that change the results?

Comment: Just about to add an Edit on a new discovery. One sec.

Comment: Also, in general, it is considered bad database design to use keywords like Name, Date, and Time as field names - Consider renaming the fields to RL_Name, RL_Date, and RL_Time or odd things can happen.

Comment: *Its the only field in SQL whose data type is nvarchar(MAX)* -- and that's exactly the hint you were looking for ;-)

Comment: nvarchar(max) gets treated as what would be called a "memo" field in Access... and not a string field. That may be the issue.

Comment: I thought it was the data type to use if data was going to be a long string of text. If I change to nvarchar(50) and the string in Details is more than 50 characters, what would happen?

Comment: Wait nvr mind. Didn't knew I  can change the limit to nvarchar(100). Thanks for the assist.

Comment: you can change it to 255 if you want and it will still be considered a string.